# When running MapFragment in Android appears error: E/GoogleCertificates: Failed to load com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, certificate

I added a mapFragment to my application. The activity runs ok but in the console I have the following error:

```
11-15 10:58:24.552
6030-6093/gchmapplications.hermandadsantamariavictoria
E/GoogleCertificates: Failed to load
com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates
pt: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version
is 0.
at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11743470:11)
at hx.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11743470:12)
at hx.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11743470:31)
at hx.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11743470:30)
at ii.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11743470:35)
at ii.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11743470:20)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ew.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11743470:141)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fc.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11743470:27)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I've found some things about the versions in gradle. I have to putted all of them in 11.0.4 because of Firebase. If not, there can be possible errors (at least is the error that appears).

Here is my Gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
```

I also have my credentials added in the Manifest.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add include the google services.Google services is required to run the maps and other features.Add google services in the top level gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```